# NGXS reuse states (Extending state classes)

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngxs

There is thing called Composition. https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/advanced/composition

And i hoped it will allow me to build reusable state for all my grids. 
Like:

```
@State<GridStateModel<any>>({
  name: 'basegridstate',
  defaults: {
    total: 0,
    rows: []
  }
})
export class BaseGridState {

  @Action(LoadGridRows)
  loadRows({patchState, dispatch, setState}: StateContext<GridStateModel<any>>) {
    patchState({
      total: 2,
    });
  }

}
```

And then i wanted to extend it many time as use in each grid to have own data.

Like

```
@State<GridStateModel<Product>>({
  name: 'cataloggrid',
  defaults: {
    total: 0,
    rows: []
  }
})
export class CatalogGridState extends BaseGridState {

  @Action(LoadCatalogRows)
  loadCatalogRows({patchState, dispatch, setState}: StateContext<GridStateModel<any>>) {
    patchState({
      total: 3,
    });
    dispatch(new LoadGridRows());
  }

}
```

But problem is dispatch call LoadGridRows on all other states that extend base one :(

Is there a way to tell it to work only with current state? Or maybe some other approach to reuse states with same logic, but custom data?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? This is exactly the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: This is not possible in NGXS. This State management library is based in CQRS and the actions are not bound to a state, meaning all the actions are global.